# Check if at least one tuple is present in a string

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuple.
I want to check if both the tuple elements are present in a string.

I came up with this code.

```
def check_if_present(user_name):
    is_present = False
    tuple_list = [('firstname1', 'secondname1'), ('firstname2', 'secondname2'), ('firstname3', 'secondname3')]
    for user, name in tuple_list:
        if user in user_name and name in user_name:
            is_present = True
    return is_present
```

`check_if_present('firstname1 secondname2 test1')` should return `False` and
`check_if_present('firstname1 secondname1 test4')` should return `True`

How can I reduce the lines of code to achieve the same logic? Or How can I achieve it efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any()` to *short-circuit* the search:

```py
tuple_list = [
    ("firstname1", "secondname1"),
    ("firstname2", "secondname2"),
    ("firstname3", "secondname3"),
]


def check_if_present(user_name, tuple_list):
    return any(
        user in user_name and name in user_name for user, name in tuple_list
    )


print(check_if_present("firstname1 secondname2 test1", tuple_list))
print(check_if_present("firstname1 secondname1 test4", tuple_list))
```

Prints:

```
False
True
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfect, just a question, on why it doesn't work if I change the code as - 
    return any(
        user and name in user_name for user, name in tuple_list
    )

Comment: @Gladiator `user and name in user_name` basically means `(user) and (name in user_name)` in which `user` evaluates always `True`

Answer (score 0):

Although using `any()` is elegant and "Pythonic", it is not the fastest solution. You can *short_circuit* the search also by a slight modification to your original code:

```
def check_if_present2(user_name, tuple_list):
    for user, name in tuple_list:
        if user in user_name and name in user_name:
            return True
    return False
```

This is about 2x faster than the `any()` version, both when the search succeeds (and is short-circuited) and when it fails (and hence is not short-circuited)